# How to call one filter inside other in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a filter named coffeefiler inside which i want to call another filter named coldcoffee

```
module ccd.coffee{
'use strict';

var myccd = angular.module('ccd.coffee');
export function coffeefilter() {
    return (value: any, key: string) => {
        if (value == null) { return 'not available'; }
        if (key === 'mocha') {
            return MochaEnum[value] || value;
        } else if (key === 'espresso') {
            return EspressoEnum[value] || value;
        } else if (key === 'coldcoffee') {
             //call filter 2 here
        return value;

    };
  }

     myccd .filter('coffeefilter', coffeefilter);
 }
```

My 2nd filter is like this:

```
 module ccd.coldcoffee{
'use strict';

var core = angular.module('ccw.coldcoffee');

export function coldcoffee() {
    return (value: any) => {
        //logic
    };

    core.filter('coldcoffee', coldcoffee);
}
```

I am unable to figureout how to inject one filter into other in typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to inject the **$filter** service in your first filter, and use that to get the 2nd one.

```js
module ccd.coffee{
'use strict';

var myccd = angular.module('ccd.coffee', ['othermodule']);
cofeefilter.$inject = ['$filter'];
export function coffeefilter($filter) {
    return (value: any, key: string) => {
        if (value == null) { return 'not available'; }
        if (key === 'mocha') {
            return MochaEnum[value] || value;
        } else if (key === 'espresso') {
            return EspressoEnum[value] || value;
        } else if (key === 'coldcoffee') {
             //call filter 2 here
             return $filter('coldcoffee')(value);
        }
        return value;

    };
  }

     myccd .filter('coffeefilter', coldcoffee);
 }
```

You can read more about the **$filter** [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

Comment: I cant access my second filter as it is in a different module. What can  i do for that

Comment: you need to add that module as a dependency to this one when you declare it. I'll edit the anser.